# How can I make 1Password for Android log in with the built in browser?

Tags: browser, password, stock-browser

I have a Droid X and have just installed 1Password. I like that I can take my passwords with em and log into websites via the phone, but it seems to only use the 1Password built in browser, which does not zoom very well and is kind of buggy.

Is it possible to log into sites with the built in browser or is this just a limitation of the 1Password software? If so it's an annoying shortcoming.

[image: autologin]

All the screenshots of this software show it using a PIN code, but since I synced it with Dropbox it's asking me to put in the same long password that I use on the computer. Is that normal or can I use a shorter pin code on the phone?

[image: PIN code]

Answer (score 1):

**The stock browser has no plug-in functionality. Until it's added you will likely never see 1password/lastpass integration in the stock browser.**

Speaking of the lastpass: It's similar to 1password and uses [dolphin's](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) plug-in system very well.

Answer (score 0):

Tap the yellow "Autologin" button to have 1Password take you to the web site and fill the login form.

To use only a PIN, adjust 1Password's security settings: bring up the application's options and tap More > Application Preferences > Application Protection, then tick the "Use PIN Code" box.